# How can i send push notification from parse local to user

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, push-notification

I want to send the push notification based on users time not based on UTC.I tried push_time: new Date(pushDt) it triggered successfully at 6.30 am(UTC) but i want to trigger it based on users local time.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("PushNtfct", function(request, status) {

function dateFormat(date, format) {

    format = format.replace("DD", (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getDate());

    format = format.replace("MM", (date.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1));

    format = format.replace("YYYY", date.getFullYear());
    return format;
}
 var todayDt = new Date();
 todayDt.setDate(todayDt.getDate()+1);

 var pushDt = dateFormat(todayDt , "YYYY-MM-DD")+ "T06:30:00";
 Parse.Push.send({
  channels: ["Daily"],
 push_time: new Date(pushDt),
  data: {
     alert: "Daily"
  }
}, { success: function() {
  console.log("Succuss with Time, Local Push notification time was sent at : " + pushDt);
  }, error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("Successfully Ran");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Fuck ..some damn error");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Installation` object has device `timeZone`, it's usually a string, you could use `moment-timezone` library to decode this string into sensible UTC+ offset which you could encode into `"Z"` part of your date to make sure your push is sent in user's local time. The way you associate `Parse.User` and `Installation` is up to you.

Comment: thank you for your i reply and i had found that they are providing the local push through curl and i had used httprequest in javascript to do that and i found a suggestion if you are using push for android then change the installation time zone "Asia/Calcutta" to "Asia/Kolkata" ignored to function properly in this timezones